# electron virtual keyboard on external child window

Tags: javascript, preload

i am working with electron@22.0.0 running on raspberry, and i need to support connecting to WIFI through captive portal. the captive portal being opened by window.open and handled with preload.js by `mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler` method. i am trying to use in the child window (captive portal) the same keyboard that i use for the app which is 'electron-virtual-keyboard', the problem is that i cannot inject any js (i.e `webFrame.executeJavaScript`) since i cannot require any module inside the child window.

for example , the following code will throw exception 'require is undefined'

captivePortalPreload.js

[image: 1]

i have tried enabling the following
`webPreferences: { devTools: true, nodeIntegration: false, webSecurity: true, contextIsolation: true, enableRemoteModule: true, sandbox: false, preload: app.isPackaged ? path.join(__dirname, 'captivePortalPreload.js') : path.join(__dirname, '../../.erb/dll/captivePortalPreload.js'), },`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please post code as text instead of image